# Sort an array according to a property which may be null

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I ve an array of objects :

```
let items = [
  { name: 'eric', value: 1 },
  { name: 'bob', value: 4 },
  { name: 'michael', value: 0 },
  { name: 'john', value: 3 },
  { name: 'brad', value: null },
  { name: 'martin', value: 2 },
  { name: 'chris', value: null }
];
```

i want to sort my array so that the objects can be sorted by the "value" attribute , and if it's null , make the object in the bottom of the array :

```
  { name: 'michael', value: 0 },
  { name: 'eric', value: 1 },
  { name: 'martin', value: 2 },
  { name: 'john', value: 3 },
  { name: 'bob', value: 4 },
  { name: 'brad', value: null },
  { name: 'chris', value: null }
```

->

i ve tried this ;

```
items.sort((a, b) => {
    return (a.orde ===null)-(b.ordre===null) || +(a.ordre>b.ordre)||-(a.ordre<b);
});
```

But seems that it's not working

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for `null` first and then sort by the value.

```js
let items = [{ name: 'eric', value: 1 }, { name: 'bob', value: 4 }, { name: 'michael', value: 0 }, { name: 'john', value: 3 }, { name: 'brad', value: null }, { name: 'martin', value: 2 }, { name: 'chris', value: null }];

items.sort(({ value: a }, { value: b }) => (a === null) - (b === null) || a - b);

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the use of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) and do something like:

```
const items = [
  { name: 'eric', value: 1 },
  { name: 'bob', value: 4 },
  { name: 'michael', value: 0 },
  { name: 'john', value: 3 },
  { name: 'brad', value: null },
  { name: 'martin', value: 2 },
  { name: 'chris', value: null }
];

const orderedItems = lodash.orderBy(items, 'value');
```

I hope this helps you.